# Python Django view function for virtual assistant app

Tags: django, artificial-intelligence

I have finished the code for a virtual assistant using neuralintents, speech_recognition, PyAudio, pyttsx3 and a json file for training the model. Now I'm trying to add it to a website I already have. Does anyone have an example of how the view function should look like ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna make a website then pyttsx3 or speech recognition won't work! you have to use javascript for that!

you can use web speech API and SpeechSynthesis for that!

```
// SpeechSynthesis
function say(text) {
        const speakObj = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
        speakObj.text = text;
        speakObj.voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices().filter(function (voice) {
            return voice.name == "Google US English";
        })[0];
        window.speechSynthesis.speak(speakObj);
    }

// Speech Recognition
function startDictation() {
        if (window.hasOwnProperty("webkitSpeechRecognition")) {
            var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
            recognition.continuous = false;
            recognition.interimResults = false;
            recognition.lang = "en-US";
            recognition.start();
            recognition.onresult = function (e) {
                console.log(e.results[0][0].transcript);
                recognition.stop();
            };
        }
    }
```

And for django view part, you have to make API or something, just make your logic there and return output from query!

```
def get_response(request, query):
    # your logic
    return <Response with JsonResponse or something...>
```

new make a request to your view using ajax...